# Show Dimension Headers on Y Axis instead of X Axis

Tags: tableau-api

So I have what seems like a pretty dumb question but I haven't been able to find an example online or figure out how to do it myself.

I want to create a visualization with the dimension headers going down the y axis and the values going across the x axis.  I'm creating a cross tab/text table kind of visualization.  It's just one name, an address, some demographic info.  If you try to use each field as it's own column, the info gets pretty cramped.  Using the transpose button doesn't work, and dropping the pills on to the row instead of column doesn't work.  I've tried changing them from dimensions to attributes, but still no luck.  Any tips would be very much appreciated.

Update:

```
Before:
ColA | ColB|
A    | B   |

After:
ColA | A
ColB | B
```

Comment: Can you share some data and explain the problem with respect to that data? Even better would be to share the screen shot of your twb(x) report file so we can see what is the issue ?

Comment: @Ajinkya Thank you for responding to this post.  I've updated the post with a simple example of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you want the dimension headers on Y and the values on X, you put the dimension pill on the rows shelf and the measure pill on the columns shelf. You might want to change a dimension to a measure and use a COUNT() or COUNTD() for example to see how many people come from a given city.

If you want to actually display several different measures next to each other (say the number of distinct cities and the number of distinct zip codes) you can drag the "Measure Names" pill on the rows and the "Measure Values" pill on the columns and add or remove the pills you need/don't need.

If this is not what you need, it would be good if you could post a screenshot of your dashboard (including the shelves and the dimensions pane). THat usually helps a lot to see where your problem is.